# open txt file using read_csv by pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to process txt file using pandas.
However, I get following error at read_csv

> CParserError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        22             Col.append(elm)
>        23 
>   ---> 24     revised=pd.read_csv(Path+file,skiprows=Header+1,header=None,delim_whitespace=True)
>        25 
>        26     TimeSeries.append(revised)
>
> C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col,
>   usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters,
>   true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter,
>   nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose,
>   skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col,
>   date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands,
>   decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment,
>   encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines,
>   skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints,
>   use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
>       560                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
>       561 
>   --> 562         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       563 
>       564     parser_f.**name** = name
>
> C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       323         return parser
>       324 
>   --> 325     return parser.read()
>       326 
>       327 _parser_defaults = {
>
> C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   read(self, nrows)
>       813                 raise ValueError('skip_footer not supported for iteration')
>       814 
>   --> 815         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
>       816 
>       817         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):
>
> C:\Users\obakatsu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   read(self, nrows)    1312     def read(self, nrows=None):    1313
>   try:
>   -> 1314             data = self._reader.read(nrows)    1315         except StopIteration:    1316             if self._first_chunk:
>
> pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read
>   (pandas\parser.c:8748)()
>
> pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory
>   (pandas\parser.c:9003)()
>
> pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows
>   (pandas\parser.c:9731)()
>
> pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows
>   (pandas\parser.c:9602)()
>
> pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error
>   (pandas\parser.c:23325)()
>
> CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in
>   line 6, saw 8

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?
My python script and example txt file I want to process is shown below.

```
Path='data/NanFung/OCTA_Tower/test/'
files=os.listdir(Path)
TimeSeries=[]
Cols=[]
for file in files:
    new=open(Path+file)
    Supplement=[]
    Col=[]
    data=[]
    Header=0
    #calculate how many rows should be skipped
    for line in new:
        if line.startswith('Timestamp'):
            new1=line.split(" ")
            new1[-1]=str(file)[:-4]
            break
        else:
            Header += 1      

    #clean col name
    for elm in new1:
        if len(elm)>0:
            Col.append(elm)

    revised=pd.read_csv(Path+file,skiprows=Header+1,header=None,delim_whitespace=True)
    TimeSeries.append(revised) 
    Cols.append(Col)
```

txt file

```
history:/NIKL6215_ENC_1/CH$2d19$2d1$20$20CHW$20OUTLET$20TEMP
20-Oct-12 8:00 PM CT  to  ?

Timestamp                  Trend Flags  Status  Value (ºC)
-------------------------  -----------  ------  ----------
20-Oct-12 8:00:00 PM HKT   {start}      {ok}    15.310 ºC 
21-Oct-12 12:00:00 AM HKT  { }          {ok}    15.130 ºC
```

Comment: Show the full traceback.

Comment: Hello, John. I have edited the question including full traceback

Answer (score 1):

It fails because the part of the file you're reading looks like this:

```
Timestamp                  Trend Flags  Status  Value (ºC)
-------------------------  -----------  ------  ----------
20-Oct-12 8:00:00 PM HKT   {start}      {ok}    15.310 ºC 
21-Oct-12 12:00:00 AM HKT  { }          {ok}    15.130 ºC
```

But there are no consistent delimiters here.  `read_csv` does not understand how to read fixed-width formats like yours.  You might consider using a delimited file, such as with tab characters between the columns.

Comment: Thanks John.   Finally, I could solve this problem using read_fwf since this data structure does not have comma or tab.

Comment: @KatsuyaObara: Yes, `read_fwf` is a good choice for your existing input format.

Answer (score -1):

## Include This line before

```
file_name = Path+file #change below line to given
```

> revised=pd.read_csv(Path+file,skiprows=Header+1,header=None,delim_whitespace=True)
>     revised=pd.read_csv(file_name,skiprows=Header+1,header=None,sep=" ")